# Carriage return in strings with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I wrote the following code in Node.js:

```
sitemap.selection = "\n";
for (const deck in series) {
  sitemap.selection += `abc\n`
}
console.log (sitemap)
```

When I run the code, it displays the following in the console:

```
selection: '\n' +
    'abc\n' +
    'abc\n' +
    'abc\n' +
    'abc\n' +
    'abc\n' +
    'abc\n' +
    'abc\n'
```

Why the string are not concatenated?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. But `console` is free in how it renders data. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(sitemap))` to see what the JSON representation looks like.